# Loading XML files with empty elements into Excel 2013

Tags: xml, excel, junit

I'm trying to create xml mapping in order to load .xml report files in JUnit format to an Excel 2013 sheet. 
I've encountered some difficulties with loading skipped tests info. I'm following this JUnit format guideline:
http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/JUnit+Format

Typical skipped testcase XML element looks like this:

```
<testcase classname="example classname" name="example testname">
    <skipped />
</testcase>
```

Passed test don't have that extra element inside testcase, so they look like this:

```
<testcase classname="example classname" name="example testname">
</testcase>
```

I want to be able to distinguish that skipped tests from the others.

After adding mapping to that XML element in my excel sheet I am able to create a column that is linked to those mapped 'skipped' elements. However, because they dont store any data, these column values are empty, even for skipped testcases. Is there any way I can read information about that skipped element into my sheet?